# angular 6 unit testing

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I am working on a project in which I am getting reports data from multiple 3rd party apis and showing it in tables with custom filters and other things. It's working fine but I am having an issue with testing. I have 1 json file consist of credentials and endpoint of each panel. As soon as app initiates I read that file.

```ts
// factory that reads file
export function akrpFactory(akrp: AkrpService) {
    return () => akrp.load();
}
// akrp.load method returns this.http.get("./assets/data.json")
// inside ngModule
providers: [
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: akrpFactory,
        deps: [AkrpService],
        multi: true
    }
]
// after this data is available throughout the application
```

In dashboard component ngAfterViewInit there is one http call

```ts
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getPerformingFeeds(this.selectedPanel.key, '0-100');
}
// this.selectedPanel.key contains one of data records from json file
// here I am getting error ('TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined') during testing
```

in .spec.ts file there only one test case. I tried to assign component.selectedPanel but still same error

```ts
it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Well I am new to angular 2+ versions, and testing also, not sure what to do. anything would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: Where is selectedPanel defined and where does it get set ?

Comment: in dashboard constructor, there is a panel dropdown list for user to select initially its data[0]

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: i am receiving error during ng test "TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined"

Comment: The error is obviously that selectedPanel is undefined. Try to console.log the value of selectedpanel after you set it in the constructor.

Comment: application is working fine, error I am getting during ng test. and I tried to assign hard coded value to component.selectedPanel for testing but still getting same error

Comment: Can you debug your test and check if `this.http.get("./assets/data.json")` is loading as expected? Normally in tests, I would mock the http call.